# Factory pattern for objects that differ in one member datatype?

Tags: c++

I keep running into the same conundrum over and over again when I try to implement a factory pattern for something like this:

```
class Base {
    template <typename T>
    void doSomethingWithMember(T){
    }
    void doing(){
        doSomethingWithMember(this->a);
    }
private:
    int a;      
};
class A: public Base {
    double a;
};
class B: public Base{
    float a;
};

struct Dictionary {
    typedef Base* (*FunctionPointer)(void);
    std::map <int, FunctionPointer> fmap;

    template <typename Target>
    static Base* construct() {
        return new Target();
    }

    Dictionary() {
        fmap.insert(std::make_pair(0, &Dictionary::construct<A>));
        fmap.insert(std::make_pair(1, &Dictionary::construct<B>));
    }

    Base* Call( int i ) const {
        std::map<int, FunctionPointer>::const_iterator entry = fmap.find( i );
        return entry == fmap.end() ? new Base() : (*entry->second)();
    }
};
```

The problem is, I cannot define `a` in `Base` because in best case it gets hidden. But without a definition of `a` i cannot implement a function for the inheritors to cope with their `a`. What I also tried was implementing `Base` as a template which led to the problem that I always had to know the returning data type (int, double, float) when creating an object trough the dictionary - saying I had no basic object type for `Base<int>`, `Base<float>`, `Base<double>`. And I do need the dictionary to give me an object according to `i` without me knowing anything else but `i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem with making `Base` a template is that you lost your common base.  However, you can get that back by making the derived class the template.  E.g.:

```
struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() { }
};
template<typename T>
struct Derived : Base {
private:
    T a;
};
```

With the above, you can return a `Base *` while having your factory construct `Derived<X>`.  Your construct() function would look something like this:

```
template<typename T>
static Base *construct() {
    return new Derived<T>();
}
```

Any functions that need to manipulate `a` would be put in `Derived<T>`, and because `Derived` is a template, you would only have to implement them once.

Comment: thank you for your wisdom kind sir. I just successfully implemented your approach into my project and works like a charm.